# How to put Search dialogue Box in middle of the Jqgrid

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid in which i have added search option and on clicking search button search Dialogue box is coming on left side of the grid and i want it to be at the middle.

here is my code...

```
jQuery("#UsersGrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#UsersGridPager', { add:false, edit: false, del: false, search: true, refresh: true,cloneToTop:true }
        , {}, // default settings for edit
          {}, // default settings for add
           {}, // delete
         {closeOnEscape: true,
         multipleSearch: true,
         closeAfterSearch: true, showQuery: true
     }, // search options
                  {}

        );
```

Answer (score 1):

See the wiki

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:singe_searching#options

you can set `left` and `top` position for the search dialog